# Как прочитать строку до знака ":"?

Tags: браузер, browser-automation-studio

[image]

Из картинки выше нужно прочитать почту до знака ":".

Как это можно реализовать в bas?

Comment: BAS == browser automation studio? Тогда погуглите browser automation studio регулярные выражения

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи на языке BAS можно использовать функцию LEFT$, которая возвращает указанное количество символов слева от заданной строки. В данном случае, мы можем использовать эту функцию, чтобы извлечь все символы из исходной строки, пока не встретится символ ":".

Ниже приведен пример кода на языке BAS, который демонстрирует этот подход:

```
10 INPUT "Введите строку: ", str$
20 pos% = INSTR(str$, ":")
30 IF pos% > 0 THEN
40     left$ = LEFT$(str$, pos% - 1)
50     PRINT "Результат: "; left$
60 ELSE
70     PRINT "Символ ':' не найден"
80 END IF
```

Этот код запрашивает у пользователя строку и затем ищет первый вхождение символа ":" в этой строке с помощью функции INSTR. Если символ ":" найден, код извлекает все символы слева от него с помощью функции LEFT$ и выводит результат. Если символ ":" не найден, код выводит сообщение об ошибке.